# Zend framework adding AWS S3 functionality?

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-web-services

I would like to know how I can make use of AWS S3 bucket as a placeholder to place application related pictures, so that zend application can fetch the pics from S3?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do is defined a config in applciation.ini file. But first off all you need to signup for the AWS and get the SECRETKEY and ACCESSKEYID. place the keys in application.ini file as follow

```
AWSAccessKeyId= "ACCESSKEY"
AWSSecretKey= "SECRETKEY"
AWSS3BucketName = "bucketName"
AWSS3GetImageUrl = "http://Name-images.s3.amazonaws.com/target-folder/"
```

once done call the predefined in layout.

```
        var AWSS3GetImageUrl = "<?php $config = Zend_Registry::get('config'); echo     
                                $config['AWSS3GetImageUrl']?>";
```

lets say you want to fetch an image from aws S3

```
 $config = Zend_Registry::get('config');
          echo '<img src="'.$config['AWSS3GetImageUrl'].{image_path_layout}.'" alt="" />';
```

hope this is informative for you. Thanks